# Trying to edit and update Google sheet with API key only (Without oAuth)

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have a Google sheet which will be controlled by another user.

I want the user to use a webpage built with PHP/Python to edit/update the sheet and be able to create new sheets to the spreadsheet.

*** I have set the permission level of the sheet to "Anyone with the link can edit."

*** This has to be done without using oAuth as this authentication asks the user to give permission to his/her **Drive and Sheets**.

I have made the sheet public and I don't want to have the access to their drive as I have nothing to do with that.

Now, will it be possible to create an interface using Sheets API with PHP to control the sheet from my page?

Let me know if it is possible or if you need any explanation.

I have been able to display the data from my sheet using the API key.

But, if I am trying to edit/update it's showing this error-

Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } } in /var/www/html/dev/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0

Answer (score 2):

Use [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and work your way from there. 403 here denotes that you don't have enough permission. It's either you're not using a high-tier scope or you need OAuth 2.